# Failing to add elements in a list inside a forEach loop - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-provider

I have a list of Followers (Model class) and it contains documentId for each user and using this documentId i am able to fetch InstaUser (again a model class) from the server using the API . The thing I want to do here is create a list of InstaUser and return it.
Inside the forEach loop i am inserting elememts to the list variable but after the exection of loop the list still remains empty.
Sharing the function snippet below , Can anyone please help me find the issue.

```
Future<List<InstaUser>> getMyFollowers() async {
List<InstaUser> list = [];
followerList.forEach((element) async {
  // followerList contains documentId
  String apiUrlForUsers =
      constants().fetchapiUrl + 'details/${element.documentId}.json';
  final currentFollowerResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrlForUsers));
  final currentFollowerData =
      json.decode(currentFollowerResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  list.add(InstaUser(
    dp: currentFollowerData['dp'],
    userName: currentFollowerData['userName'],
    website: currentFollowerData['website'],
    bio: currentFollowerData['bio'],
    title: currentFollowerData['title'],
    email: currentFollowerData['email'],
    keyIdFromServer: currentFollowerData['keyIdFromServer'],
    uid: currentFollowerData['uid'],
  ));
  print(
      'Current length = ${list.length.toString()} ${currentFollowerData['title']}');
});
print('length = ${list.length}');
return list;}
```

Log report:-
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
Reloaded 10 of 1120 libraries in 738ms.
I/flutter (19300): length = 0
I/flutter (19300): Current length = 1 Uzumaki Naruto`enter code here`
I/flutter (19300): Current length = 2 Uchiha Sasuke

I am also not getting why its printing the length before any other print statements.